# new numpy array creation from two other numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 numpy arrays in the following format

```
array([[2, 2, 7, 1],
       [5, 0, 3, 1],
       [2, 9, 8, 8],
       [5, 7, 7, 6]])
```

and

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8],
       [9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

I want to combine these to the following format

```
array([[[2, 2, 7, 1],[1,2,3,4]],
       [[5, 0, 3, 1],[5,6,7,8]],
       [[2, 9, 8, 8],[9,10,11,12]],
       [[5, 7, 7, 6],[13,14,15,16]]])
```

The real data which I am handling contains very large amount of data(5000 in one row). SO working with pandas doesnt solve the case. Is there any efficient method when the data is very huge for creating a format like this

Comment: My bad... corrected now

Comment: I think you are looking for `np.stack` with appropriate `axis` argument, e.g. `np.stack((array1, array2), axis=1)`.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

```
arr1 = np.array([[2, 2, 7, 1],
                 [5, 0, 3, 1],
                 [2, 9, 8, 8],
                 [5, 7, 7, 6]])

arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [9, 10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15, 16]])

arr3 = np.stack((arr1, arr2), axis=1)
print(arr3)
```

Output

```
[[[ 2  2  7  1]
  [ 1  2  3  4]]

 [[ 5  0  3  1]
  [ 5  6  7  8]]

 [[ 2  9  8  8]
  [ 9 10 11 12]]

 [[ 5  7  7  6]
  [13 14 15 16]]]
```

Comment: @imhans33, if that works, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: acceted.. pls upvote the qs too